# skip consistency check in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to insert a record even if the data received is less than expected number of columns?
I frequently get the following message.

```
Too few columns: expected 24 column(s) but got 22 column(s)
```

If I ignore such records using max_bad_record option, I loose the data. I will like to see an option that will forcefully insert a record by adding extra delimiters if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Sheldon mentions below, if you specify allowJaggedRows, a row that has too few columns will get NULL for all of the remaining columns. If you have missing columns in the middle of the row, however, BigQuery doesn't know which column is missing, and if the types don't match up, you'll get an error for the row.

There has been some talk about adding all rows with errors into a separate table, so that you could then process them and append them to the original table. If you would find this useful let me know.

Comment: Please add --force option assuming that missing columns are at the end. The user who uses this option will be on his own when it comes to data integrity.

Comment: I reccommend that data integrity be handled in the extraction and transformation steps before the data is ingested into BigQuery. In general, I don't think the analysis layer of a data pipeline should be responsible for handling data consistency problems coming from other parts of the pipeline.

Comment: If I need 3 column pipe separated file, I can use awk # awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {print $1,$2,$3}' # But I can not automate the import flow. I have to unzip, open the file, run awk, zip and continue. # force option would really help, Please consider.

Comment: BigQuery now supports loading CSV data with missing optional columns: see allowJaggedRows documentation in the [BigQuery Jobs Reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs)

Answer (score 1):

Preprocess the data to be in the right format; depends on your platform if you can use perl, sed or whatever.

Perhaps you can simply add the extra delimiters on all records, if bigquery won't complain about too many fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can now do this using the `allowJaggedRows` option in the job load configuration. This option will cause a load to "Accept rows that are missing trailing optional columns. The missing values are treated as nulls." See the [BigQuery Jobs Reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs) for a complete list of all job configuration options.

This option is available on the bq command line tool via: `bq load --allow_jagged_rows` and in the [BigQuery UI](http://www.google.com) under "advanced options" when creating and loading a new table.